# Is it good practice to assign a value of FALSE to a function at the beginning and then TRUE only when it reaches the end?

Tags: vba, function, excel

For the functions I have, I have many scenarios where, based on IF checks, I have

```
MyFunction = False
Exit Function
```

When it reaches the end of the function, then and only then does the `MyFunction = True` occur. Because of the repetition of the `False` assignment, I was wondering if it is good practice to instead initially set `MyFunction = False` for example after the `Dim` of variables, and then only have it become true when everything goes through properly. Is there any reason this would either increase robustness or decrease it?

Comment: I think the performance difference would be negligible. Not sure what you mean in robustness. It would really only affect the readability of your code IMO.

Comment: That's the way I always do it. To me it's defensive programming. The function has failed until you explicitly set it to success. Makes perfect sense to me. To me it improves readability but only because I'm used to doing it that way. In theory you are saving on code that explicitly sets it to false.

Comment: In your experience, is readability enhanced by having shorter code blocks (like if I were to remove all the `False` assignments and just have one at the beginning) or by having more explicit instructions throughout (like having a `MyFunction = False` wherever it becomes applicable)?

Answer (score 2):

Every type of variable has an 'empty' value (after Dim without setting it to something). Boolean values are always false... numerical values are 0, strings are "" and variant / objects are empty... setting it to something it already is, only can slow down.
Knowing that its not neccessary to set a bool to false after dim... (or a numerical value to 0)

**EDIT:**
This also counts for functions even if there is something like `Function MyFunction(Optional a as Boolean = True) as Boolean` `a` will be `False` at the start then it checks if there is something to set to and if not it will be set to true.... also the function itself will be false at the start. It is differnt when doing something in C or other scripting languages, but VBA is set to change all bits inside a reserved range for a value to `0`.

Comment: So a VBA function is, by default, guilty until proven innocent, so to speak? Is that for sure? I.e. if I never explicitly state `MyFunction = False` at any point, and then just put an Exit Function in, it is guaranteed to return false? (I did not know this).

Comment: simply create a sub `Dim x as ****` (**** to whatever you want) and then `Debug.Print x`.. a variable can't be empty for real. when you `Dim` it, there is simply a part of memory set to hold the value of it... it wil allways be (binary) `0000000000000000....` having a bool only contains 1 bit being 0 after `Dim` -> false...